# Maxpool with multiple instances in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

If I have multiple instances on Azure and a webapp which has a connection string with maxpool:
the connection string max pool * instance count should equal the max allowed in the SQL tier , right? or should I set the maxpool to be equal to max for the tier

Example: SQL with max connections if 2400
Instance count is 10
Should the connection string for the app has sql connection string 240 or 2400 to be within limits?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The pool size is defined per instance (actually per process, you might have multiple web jobs running on the same instance). So, if you want to guarantee that you are always below the limit, you should divide total size on instance/process count, 240 in your example.